# How do I configure pretty urls on my WordPress blog?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress (and PHP). I am trying to make WP MVC's sample run on my wordpress:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mvc/

I added the plugin and can see data listed in my events menu but when I click View, it tries to browse:

http://localhost/mysite/events/1

and it can't I get 404 error and I suspect it is most probably due the fact that Wordpress is not configured for pretty urls.

So I went in my admin site and under Settings/Permalinks I selected 2nd option of Day and name and I still get 404 error. Also on my home pages my posts disappeared and I get:

```
Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps searching will help.
```

Has anybody had any experience with WP MVC?

PHP is making my head hurt:(

Comment: This is not a programming question so it's off-topic here.  Maybe [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a PHP guy but can try going into your **httpd.conf** and see if your rewrite module is commented or not. If there is any # in front of it remove it and then restart wamp and try. I think this is mostly due to the fact that your module is not enabled. Let me know if it helped you.

Specifically this line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure there is no # in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a permalink structure in Settings > Permalinks, WordPress attempts to write an .htaccess file to the root of your site, probably similar to this default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My file permissions are locked down a bit tighter than that, so I see the suggested contents at the bottom of the Permalink page, with some brief instructions. Are you seeing something similar? Did WordPress create an .htaccess file? Do you have mod_rewrite installed? (I don't recall if WordPress can autodetect mod_rewrite.)